# Any suggestions what is happening with include and @include

Tags: php

When I use:

```
include "../common/common_functions.php";
include "../common/functions.php";
include '../../common/global_functions.php';
```

my browser gives me a lot of warnings, but when i use:

```
@include "../common/common_functions.php";
@include "../common/functions.php";
@include '../../common/global_functions.php';
```

it's working. I know what is the difference between them, but is there any other explanation because files are there and its working with `@` but I know that it's not good to be used! Any suggestion what might be other reason?

It gives me this errors :

```
Warning: include(../../common/constants.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/ebelejnik/trunk/src/www/root/teadmin/common/common_functions.php on line 4
Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '../../common/constants.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/ebelejnik/trunk/src/www/root/teadmin/common/common_functions.php on line 4
```

I understand why it gives me these errors. Because I make a `subdir` and my file system looks like this:

```
/root /common /teadmin /common /admin_pages
```

And when I call a file in `/teadmin/common` from `/teadmin/admin_pages`, it starts to execute it but it calls several files from `/root/common` and can't find them because i use a path like this:

```
include '../common/constants.php';
```

When I do it like this:

```
include '../../common/constants.php';
```

This is from file `common_functions.php` which is in `/root/teadmin/common/`. It's working in a second way from `/root/teadmin/admin_pages/` but gives me an error in `/root/teadmin/` when i call it. Is there a problem with doing it like this:

```
include '../common/constants.php';
@include '../../common/constants.php';
```

Comment: What do the warnings say? Does it work even with the warnings?

Comment: You should post those warnings so we can help you remove them without simply suppressing them

Comment: try `include_once('../common/common_functions.php');` and so on.

Comment: -1 for not posting the actual warnings, making question pointless

Comment: The files are not included and the `@` does not change that fact. All it does is suppress the message saying that the files are not included.

Comment: why do you say "it's working" while it is not?

Comment: it's working when it's include '../../common/constants.php'; but in one folder up when i call constants it throw me those warnings.now it's include '../common/constants.php';
        @include '../../common/constants.php';
and is working from everywhere without warnings.Is there a problem to stay like this?\

Comment: IT IS NOT working! there is no warning but no include as well. try to use included file and see. It is NOT working.

Answer (score 3):

@ is the error suppresion operator in php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Errors are good, it's php's way of communicating with you.  They might be worth looking into.  Perhaps you are using deprecated functionality, you should post your errors too.

Comment: learn to love the error!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep in mind, that `..` is counted using the path of the script, requested by browser, not the current `include`d script.

You can use the following to  construct path, relative to current script:

```
include __DIR__ . "/../common/common_functions.php";
```

or in earlier  PHP versions:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . "/../common/common_functions.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt how relative paths work and how PHP sets the working directory to the invoked script, then make all paths absolute:

```
include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/common/constants.php";
include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/common/functions.php";
```

They are absolute in relation to the "web server root directory". (Note that absent array key quotes are valid in double quote context, and only there.)

Answer (score -2):

`@` is a silence operator. This hide all warnings, so you can make some beaty warning like:

```
if (!@include('some_file.php')){
    echo 'There is a problem with script';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Bad idea. Very bad idea.

Comment: I have forgotten about stop script after error.

Comment: Too lazy to type curly braces? Your code doesn't do what you think it does. (I was about to countervote the @-haters, but this snippet isn't overly useful either.)

Comment: there are no @-haters. there are *sane programmers.*